# Get a Timeout error in Slack. How do I handle this error in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, slack-api

I'm currently developing my own slack app using NodeJS.

My program calls an external API. Sometimes it is unable to respond within 3000 msec and Slack displays a timeout error. How to handle this error in NodeJS?

The Slack-API provides a `response_url` to send a request. What is the best solution here?

This is my code. It works for me but it's not the best solution.

```
if (time_result < 2500) {
    return res.ok(foo)
} else {
    request({
            url: response_url,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: foo,
            method: 'POST',
            json: true
        }, 
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                sails.log(error);
            } else {
                sails.log(body)
            }
        })
    return res.json({
        text: 'message is comming :)'
    });
}
```

Comment: Slack won't tell you about the timeout message it sent to a user. So if you want to log that in particular, it might be hard?
Generally, the way I handle this is to kick off an asynchronous process (which handles the lengthy task) and after that immediately respond to the Slack request with `200 OK`. Once the asynchronous process is complete, it posts to Slack using the `response_url` as you already suggested.

Comment: We estimate upfront on the length of the task: Is it a simple fetch (way below 3 secs) or a task doing something like a waterfall with more than one action - for the latter we always return immediately with an Ephemeral message followed by the real response as @WilhelmKlopp suggested. We are using Sails.js and attaching the response_url to the `req` object so that we can respond whenever we want or wherever this request is handled.